Can libgpiod lose edge events on a Raspberry Pi?
I am using the C++ wrapper of libgpiod 1.6 on a RPi to detect falling edges on a GPIO pin. The interrupt rate is typically 100-200 Hz. I am exactly following this example: https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/blob/v1.6.x/bindings/cxx/examples/gpiomoncxx.cpp
My program has to respond on every interrupt before the peripheral deasserts the interrupt line, so it should be impossible to overload the RPi with events. The RPi seems to cope very well with the high interrupt frequency.
My program runs for a while, but at some point gpiod::line::event_wait() does not return before the timeout. I can see with the Logic Analyzer that the IO line is asserted, so I should have gotten an event.
Is it possible that libgpiod loses edge events? How is that possible? I thought that edges are detected in hardware and that it is literally impossible to lose any interrupt event.

Richard, the short answer is no. While it's worth noting you are using the 1.6x version which relies on the deprecated version of the kernel gpio uABI. In that same repository you will also find the 2.0x version based on the gpio_v2 uABI. See GPIO Character Device Userspace API. That said, there is no reason you can't catch edges on the nanosecond scale. To provide a meaningful answer all will need to know how your edges are generated (or are you literally just using the linked example?)

I've often found the libraries confusing, and even more so wrappers to the libraries. I've gotten to where I prefer simply using the kernel provided interface linked above (the libgpiod 2.0x version was a complete rewrite, and done quite well, but it implements every feature of the kernel interface -- making it a bit confusing). Which was motivation just to learn the kernel interface and cut out the middle-men. I have a short example that reads and writes edges in C at GPIO_V2 ioctl example which may help.

And let me qualify the "can the library miss an edge?" answer to say it is possible, but rare. This largely has to do with the PiOS not being a RealTime OS. Everything running in Linux is subject to the process scheduler - which does rely on whatever else your Pi is doing and when the interrupts are scheduled to be handled in the processor pipeline. Your code should be tolerant of that and work to handle a missed rising or falling edge. Each event is also timestamped and that is available in the event struct which may help you track down the issue if you are consistently missing edges.

The example above writes one edge every 5 microseconds and reads from a separate thread as fast as it can. At that rate you will occasionally miss an edge. There is a minuscule delay between the time the edge goes high and the circuitry senses that and triggers the interrupt. The same occurs for the falling edge. The amazing part is an overwhelming majority of the time, there is 100% edge capture.

@David Let me clarify: After receiving an edge, the peripheral will not produce another edge unless the RPi host acknowledges the interrupt. That way I can rule out that the RPi does not cope with the interrupt rate. So I wonder how the GPIO interrupts are implemented under the hood. Is the Linux kernel polling the hardware or does it use a hardware trigger?

If the Linux kernel polls the GPIO line under the hood (on the RPi), then I see how it could miss edges. But if edge detection works in hardware, I don't see it.

That is a good question and one where we meet the kernel-space and user-space divide. An interrupt at it's core is simply a bit set in an interrupt register that tells the kernel when that interrupt is ready. Now how that is implemented is quite different between a Linux box and say the Pi-pico. Linux will detect the interrupt on the kernel side and generate a signal that propagates to user-space which you catch in your defined signal handler. It can be implemented a couple of ways, but the sa_sigaction approach is preferred. On your side, you poll for the ready descriptor (usually).

Unfortunately, what the kernel provides varies by peripheral. Meaning how interrupts (or signals) are used for PWM, differs from the ioctl() interface you poll with for GPIO. The frustrating (challenging) part is you end up having to make friends with each of the different ways the peripheral you are using does it. Here is where microcontrollers like the Pico, or Arduino or TI MSP32 boards shine. No OS, you have the datasheet and address for each register and a description of what each bit controls and you simply use the prescribed function template to grab that interrupt (and turn it off)

I've got to catch a few hours of sleep before the sun comes up, so we can continue this in about 8 hour or so.

A few things to clarify here.  The kernel relies on interrupts, not polling.  Interrupts are handled in the kernel in interrupt context and so do not involve the process scheduler running a userspace process.   This has nothing to do with userspace signals.  Events are queued within the kernel for later processing by userspace. That queue may overflow if userspace is too slow handling events.  If you upgrade to libgpiod v2 then you get access to event sequence numbers and can check for event queue overflow.

In short, given your description of your setup, with you having to explicitly ack the interrupt in the peripheral, then don't see how you could lose events.  More likely you lost the ack.

I haven't told the whole truth. My program waits for interrupts on 2 different GPIO pins in 2 different threads. Both use the same gpio device. Could that be a problem?

My program waits for interrupts on 2 different GPIO pins in 2 different threads. Both use the same gpio device. What you said is nonsense. I mean each sentence has a meaning on its own, but those two together are kinda confusing.  Can you rephrase that?

Waiting for events on separate lines is not a problem, as long as they are separate requests.  If you were using a single request that includes both lines, and I'm not sure if that is even possible for libgpiod v1, then you should only have one thread waiting for events on that request.  But separate requests are independent of each other. And you haven't mentioned how you ack the interrupt in the peripheral.

@0andriy What you said is nonsense.  I wouldn't go that far - I think I got what he means - both lines are on the same device, which is not unusual.  His concern is that there is some contention - but the kernel deals with that.

@RichardW - note, in all things GPIO_Vx or how the kernel handles it, I'll deffer to the crazy Aussie warthog -- he is one of the authors after all. (that's Kent if you are unfamiliar with his e-mail address)

the kernel deals with that  - assuming the device driver isn't buggy.

Sorry, I am mixing up the terms interrupt and event. Coming from bare metal microcontrollers , I am used to deal with hardware interrupts caused by IO pins. But here we have a kernel in between and I shouldn’t use the term interrupt in a user-space program. Sorry, sorry. I am waiting for falling edges on two different IO lines. Each line is monitored by a different thread and no lingpiod objects are shared.

No problem - I understood what you meant.  For other's reference this issue is being tracked in libgpiod, even if it isn't likely to be a libgpiod problem, since SO isn't the right place to be debugging.
